# Remote I/O costs with a Content Delivery Network

Tags: directory

As far as I know, the time complexity of scanning a directory and the amount of files in said directory are correlated due to I/O costs. Would the administrative costs of placing the files in a hashed directory tree for uploading/downloading files through a CDN API be worth it for the added efficiency?

For instance, given a filename `foo.mp3`, the `MD5` hash for this is `10ebb1120767e9de166e0f5905077cb1`. Thus, storing `foo.mp3` in `./10/eb/foo.mp3` would allow for less files per directory (assuming MD5 generates patterns with in Base36, this allows for `36^2` root directories with `36^2` subdirectories each and little chance of hash collision)

Considering the directories themselves are not loaded, would the I/O costs of directory scanning still exist with direct uploading/downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory such a technique would greatly reduce bandwidth costs, however it would also increase CPU costs.  I suggest you have a look at [Rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) and see how this tool has solved this problem without the use of hash directories.  Also given specific data patters it is possible to have hash collisions where two files would have the exact same MD5 hash.  This only becomes a problem if the new and old version of a specific file have the same MD5 hash.  It is rare, but it does happen.